# High amount of http read timeouts on azure

Tags: azure, networking

When we migrated our apps to azure from rackspace, we saw almost 50% of http requests getting read timeouts.

We tried placing the client both inside and outside azure with the same results. The client in this case is also a server btw, so no geographic/browser issues either.
We even tried increasing the size of the box to ensure azure wasn't throttling. But even using D boxes for a single request, the result was the same.

Once we moved out apps out of azure they started functioning properly again.

Each query was done directly on an instance using a public ip, so no load balancer issues either.

Almost 50% of queries ran into this issue. The timeout was set to 15 minutes.

Region was US East 2

Comment: i'm assuming you need a timeout that high for internal processing like reports or something like that, right?

Comment: Which Azure service?  VM's?  Cloud Services?

Comment: The query was supposed to return in <100ms. The timeout should rb lower on our part but fact is it didn't return after 15 mins

Comment: Azure Vms. A8 instance.

Comment: Actually it was both A8 and D instances. 8 core boxes. We switched to high powered boxes to ensure azure wasn't throttlin network

Comment: Did you determine whether the timing-out requests are reaching your machines at all?

Comment: We didn't. That said we also found that connections out of azure had trouble. The server in this case would frequently timeout connecting to zookeeper which was outside azure

Answer (score 0):

Having 50% of HTTP requests timing out is not normal behavior. This is why you need to analyze what is causing those timeouts by validating the requests are hitting your VM. For this, I would recommend you running a packet capture on your server and analyze response times, as well as look for high number of retransmissions; it is even better if you can take a simultaneous network trace on your clients machines so you can do TCP sequence number analysis and compare packets sent vs received. 
If you are seeing high latencies in the packet capture or high number of retransmissions, it requires detailed analysis. I strongly suggest you to open a support incident so Microsoft support can help you investigate your issue further.